# Send Cstring using and get answer using Win Message

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to send string using win message and get back answer. Does following method has memory management problems regarding CString?

Call:

```
CString params = "Hello";
SendMessage(hWnd,WM_AUT_MESSAGE, (WPARAM)&params,0);
```

Answer:

```
LRESULT CMainWindow::OnMessageAuthorise(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CString *pStr = (CString*)wParam;
    *pStr="Bye";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `params` is a stack variable. I don't know about windows stuff but you better make sure `params` is still there when `CMainWindow::OnMessageAuthorise` gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks OK. SendMessage blocks and does not return until OnMessageAuthorise returns, so even with a pointer to a stack variable there is no race condition. (Assuming, of course, that all of this happens within the same process.)

Comment: This happens in different threads. Is it OK that size of "Hello" and "Bye" might be different? What if "Bye" will be bigger than "Hello"?

Comment: All that is OK.  CString takes care of its memory allocation.